# Influence of Substratums

Tags: historical-linguistics, substrate

There is a claim in the book ,,Französische Sprachwissenschaft" (by Johannes Klare, 2011) that says: ,,*The substrate influences can affect all linguistic levels, especially the phonetic system and vocabulary.*"

And my question is why are these levels so affected and morphology and syntax apparently not so much?

Answer (score 7):

W.r.t. phonetics, when learning a second language, it is hardest to stop applying the rules of your first language (you will always talk with an accent), hence Etruscans who pick up the invading language Latin will have an Etruscan accent (substrate influence). Depending on the social situation, the incomers may also be motivated to emulate the speech of locals: plus, the locals may care for the children of the incomers (or frequently be the mothers of their children), the result being that the child is raised bilingually where the caretaker's accented version of the incoming language prevails over the phonetic pattern of monolingual outsiders.

Lexical items are extremely easy to borrow (morphological borrowing is particularly difficult). It's easy to have two systematically different words for "pumpkin", because words are just individual things (everything else is part of a complex system). This is why when doing comparative reconstruction, we have to look for hard-to-borrow things as representing "the original situation" and we don't (or shouldn't) rely just on vocabulary similarities. There are various reasons why incomers would jettison original lexical item, for example the local thing is considered to be superior, or the incomers didn't have the thing.

Comment: Aha, a chance to mention [metatypy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatypy)

Answer (score 2):

Substrate interference are often found in phonology, because speakers of the original language often retain their idiosyncrasies of pronunciation and stress in the language change. Syntax and (more rarely) morphology can also be affected.

In contrast, substrate influence in vocabulary is usually limited to areas for which the mass of newly immigrated speakers have no terms (for example, in the case of field, place and river names or animal and plant names) or which were not needed in contact.

For example, the Gallic name for the larch survived in French, although the Romans of course also knew it.